# printf apostrophe is replaced by Æ in C

Tags: c, windows, string, formatting

This is part of my first comp sci assignment, we are writing a C program that evaluates several equations. Here is the code that is giving the wonky result:

```
// 1. Newton’s Second Law of Motion
printf("Newton's Second Law of Motion \nPlease enter mass and acceleration as decimal-point values separated by a comma (ex. 150.0,5.5): ");
scanf("%lf, %lf", &mass, &accel);
printf("Newton’s Second Law of Motion: force = mass * acceleration = %lf * %lf = %lf\n\n\n", mass, accel, mass*accel);
```

When the program is run, the first printf displays fine, but the second displays "NewtonÆs" instead of "Newton's".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Comment: *Text* is a very, very complicated topic. While you're focusing on learning C, stick to basic English characters until you're ready do to spend some serious time to think about the intricacies of digital writing.

Comment: That's Unicode codepoint \u2019, "Right Single Quotation Mark".  Not much of it will be recognizable after the compiler and the console/terminal you use munch it.  Write your own code, avoid copying from web pages.

Comment: It works here out of the box. The terminal settings must match the source encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using UNICODE?

Seems like there's a difference in the apostrophe: `Newton’s` vs `Newton's`. Did you copy-paste from somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I must have! That fixed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The single-byte character `’`, with value 0x92, will display differently on different systems depending on the codepage currently in effect.

[Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (common in the US) displays a `Æ` character for this value.

Other codepages, like [codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (Western European), display `’`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different characters used for the apostrophe. The first `'` is part of the ASCII character set that is at the base of all modern character sets, and is the same in all of them. The second `’` is an extended character that is not part of the base, and is subject to different interpretations depending on your character set or code page. The character `Æ` is at position 0x00c6 in the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding.

Answer (score 1):

What's most likely happening here is that you copied text from a source instead of hand entering it.  That source likely had UNICODE encoded characters instead of 7/8bit ASCII chars.

I could be wrong but I'm fairly certain that printf only supports 8bit ASCII, and therefore truncated the leading data of your UNICODE widechar apostrophe.

The character you want is 0x27 (decimal 39) '

The character you typed is decimal 92 ’ which depending on the codepage may display as Æ

I hope that clears it up.